# In swift remote notification is there a way to display a different message in the banner other than the one received from server when app is killed?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, remote-notifications

If my payload from the server is

```
{   "aps" : {  "alert" : "You got a mail";
    "badge" : 0;
}
"user": { "name" : "Nicole" }  }`
```

And It also gives me some other data about the name of user who sent it . Is there a way to display custom message in the format : "Nicole sent a mail" in the notification center or banner ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible since `iOS 10` by creating a `Notification Service Extension`. You can check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) for its details. Also, [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/rich-notifications/) is a good tutorial from Avanderlee that explains how to add `Notification Service Extension` to you app.